Relationship between conserved quantities along the streamlines of a steady flow
For a steady flow, suppose that the two fields $A(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $B(\boldsymbol{x})$ are conserved along streamlines, so that
$\boldsymbol{v}\cdot \nabla A = 0$ and $\boldsymbol{v}\cdot \nabla B = 0$,
where $\boldsymbol{v}$ is the velocity. Suppose that we also have found a function of the flow variables that is conserved along streamlines - in analogy with the Bernoulli function, we call this function $H$. Then
$\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\nabla H = 0$.
Does it follow that $H$ is a function of $A$ and $B$, namely
$H=H(A,B)$?
If this were the case, could we then safely conclude that
$\frac{\partial H}{\partial C} = 0$
for any scalar field, $C(\boldsymbol{x})$, that is not conserved along streamlines.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Happy New Year!
